# error in installing PostgreSQL?

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

I have a error message during install PostgreSQL : "Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster" but no error message "Error running post install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Error reading C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/postgresql.conf".

I have tried to do the following steps but still appear an above error:

Uninstall the PostgreSQL and delete the data directory in the installation folder.
Create a new Windows user named postgres and add it to the Administrators group.
Restart your computer.
Open cmd (command prompt) as the postgres command using the following command: runas /user:postgres cmd.exe
A new window appears, you need to run the installer file from this window.

Help me , thanks !

Comment: I would try to *login* with an `administrator` account (a `runas` is not always good enough), and try to perform the installation from that account. NOTE: it always helps to point out which *version* of Windows you're using, and which of the several distributions of PostgreSQL you're trying to install (is it [EnterpriseDB?](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) [BigSQL?](https://www.bigsql.org/postgresql/installers.jsp) any other?)

Comment: I downloaded file .exe from EnterpriseDB , I have tried to download by running Administrator , but it's still has error.

Comment: If binaries have been installed properly, you could use initdb to create the database server in a different folder. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-initdb.html